# Recibo arreglo vacío al intentar borrar un usuario en LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

Buenas tengo un problema el cual no consigo solucionar, a ver si podéis ayudarme

Tengo implementado el sistema de login con breeze, la cosa es que me he creado por requerimientos de mi aplicación un controlador UserController.php  y a su vez las rutas para poder realizar el crud de los usuarios.

En la vista users.index  llega correctamente el objeto users que le paso desde el controlador, voy mostrando usuario en una tabla y a su derecha le pongo botones con la opción de borrar, editar y tal.

La cosa es que al pulsar borrar, lo que me llega al método destroy es un arreglo vacío [] y no consigo que llegue correctamente dicho objeto al metodo destroy.

Ruta para el crud de usuarios:

`Route::resource('users', UserController::class)->middleware(['auth', 'verified', 'check.direction']);`

Vista index de usuario:

```
<x-app-layout>
    <div class="overflow-x-auto relative mt-4">
        <table class="mx-auto text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
            <thead class="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
                <th scope="col" class="py-3 px-6">Operarios</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($usuarios as $usuario)
                <tr class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
                        <td class="py-4 px-6"><a href="{{route('users.show', $usuario)}}">{{ $usuario->nombre }}</a></td>


                        <td class="px-6 text-center">
                            <a href="{{ route('users.edit', $usuario) }}"><button class="focus:outline-none text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2 mr-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-900">Editar</button></a>
                            <form action="{{ route('users.destroy', $usuario) }}" method="POST" class="inline">
                                @method('DELETE')
                                @csrf
                                <button type="submit" class="focus:outline-none text-white bg-red-700 hover:bg-red-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-red-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2 dark:bg-red-600 dark:hover:bg-red-700 dark:focus:ring-red-900">Borrar</button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" class="text-end py-3 px-16 " >
                            <a href="{{ route('users.create') }}"><button class="focus:outline-none text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2 mr-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-900">Añadir operario</button></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</x-app-layout>
```

método destroy:

```
public function destroy(User $usuario)
    {

        return $usuario;

    }
```

recibo el arreglo vacío, si utilizo el dd($usuario) aparece como si no conectara con la base de datos. no sé en que estoy fallando.

```
App\Models\User {#1350 ▼ // app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php:110
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: array:2 [▶]
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  +usesUniqueIds: false
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #visible: []
  #fillable: array:7 [▶]
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
  #accessToken: null
}
```

he estado probando varias cosas para saber de donde venía el problema. pero sigo en el mismo punto, sé que falla en el momento que pulsas borrar al usuario y a través del
"route('users.destroy', $usuario)" cuando llega al método destroy llega como arreglo vacío y no sé el por qué ni que mas puedo intentar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por como definiste la ruta:

```
Route::resource('users', UserController::class)->middleware(['auth', 'verified', 'check.direction']);
```

Probablemente el parametro sea `user` y no `usuario`. Lo puedes comprobar corriendo `php artisan route:list`:

```
DELETE          users/{user}........ users.destroy › App\Http\Controllers\UserController@destroy
```

Luego tendrías que modificar el nombre de la variable que inyectas en la función `destroy`:

```
public function destroy(User $usuario)
{ //...
```

para que coincida con el nombre del parámetro de la ruta:

```
public function destroy(User $user)
{ //...
```

Fuente: [Implicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#implicit-binding)

> Laravel resuelve automáticamente los modelos Eloquent definidos en rutas o acciones de controlador cuyos nombres de variables *typados* coinciden con un nombre de segmento de ruta.
> Dado que la variable `$user` está *typado* como el modelo eloquent `App\Models\User` y el nombre de la variable coincide con el segmento URI `{user}`, Laravel inyectará automáticamente la instancia del modelo que tenga una `ID` que coincida con el valor correspondiente del URI de solicitud.

Answer (score 0):

Hola por lo que veo el problema que estás teniendo parece estar relacionado con cómo estás pasando el objeto User a la ruta de eliminación en tu vista. En tu código, estás utilizando el enlace en la forma route('users.destroy', $usuario) para enviar el objeto User al método destroy en tu controlador, pero parece que el objeto User no está siendo recuperado correctamente en el método.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es pasar en la ruta solo el ID de usuario. De la forma

route('users.destroy', $usuario->id)

De esa manera en el HTML se convierte en un número y no un objeto.
Cómo ya dijeron en respuestas anteriores tu función destroy recibirá un ID pero al indicarle que es un objeto de la clase user. Laravel encontrará el usuario y te.dara el objeto $usuario cómo tu lo necesitas.
Saludos